# Trying to predict image with trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, conv-neural-network

RE-EDITTED: I trained a CNN model with rehsaped images.
`model.add(Conv2D(32,3,padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=(224,224,3)))`
I'm now trying to use that trained model on an image.
My code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
size=224
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/home/philip/QAME696/savedmodel/CNNModel')
image = cv2.imread("/home/philip/QAME696/rain.png")
resized=cv2.resize(image,(size,size)) # keras.util.load_image
prediction=model.predict([resized])
# Check its architecture
prediction
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (32, 224, 3)
```

Upon changing line to `model.predict(resized[np.newaxis])`, I get this:

```
2023-01-20 21:27:47.896204: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic/share/euslisp/jskeus/eus//Linux64/lib:/home/philip/svp2_ws/devel/lib:/home/philip/coverage_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/melodic/lib
2023-01-20 21:27:47.896269: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2023-01-20 21:28:02.830662: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /home/philip/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/../../lib64:/opt/ros/melodic/share/euslisp/jskeus/eus//Linux64/lib:/home/philip/svp2_ws/devel/lib:/home/philip/coverage_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/melodic/lib
2023-01-20 21:28:02.830730: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2023-01-20 21:28:02.830782: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (philip-Blade): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2023-01-20 21:28:02.832157: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-01-20 21:28:20.927716: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
```

I have to rebuild tensorflow to get this to work? and install `cudart`?

Answer (score 0):

If the model has a single input, you should pass a 4-D array to it, instead of a list of 3-D arrays:

```py
model.predict(resized[np.newaxis])
```

this expands the array by adding an axis at the beginning to account for batch size (i.e. batch size is 1 here).

On the other hand, giving a list of inputs like you did is for models with multiple inputs only, and not for multiple images in a batch.

Comment: I re-editted my question. I'm getting new errors.

Comment: this is error because you don't have cuda installed. Does your machine have a GPU?  you need to install cudatoolkit: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip